# UITextField to Input Money Amount

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, swift2, uitextfielddelegate

I am developing a Point Of Sales app.

So I would like to

1. Let's say User input `100000` but I want it to automatically show up `100,000`. and `1000000` become `1,000,000`
2. The second problem is that, I don't want user to be able to input `.` themselves.
3. Third problem is that since this is money, we can't let user to enter 0 in the beginning.

Any ideas?

So far I have managed to restrict the input to decimal digits only

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

        let numberSet: NSCharacterSet = NSCharacterSet.decimalDigitCharacterSet().invertedSet;
        return string.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(numberSet).length > 0 || string == "";
}
```

Thank you very much

***P.S.: I do not need any decimal places, also we need to take into account when the user change the cursor position when hitting backspace***

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Xcode 9 • Swift 4**

```
import UIKit

class IntegerField: UITextField {
    var lastValue = 0
    let maxValue = 1_000_000_000
    var amount: Int {
        if let newValue = Int(string.digits), newValue < maxValue {
            lastValue = newValue
        } else if !hasText {
            lastValue = 0
        }
        return lastValue
    }
    override func didMoveToSuperview() {
        textAlignment = .right
        keyboardType = .numberPad
        text = Formatter.decimal.string(for: amount)
        addTarget(self, action: #selector(editingChanged), for: .editingChanged)
    }
    @objc func editingChanged(_ textField: UITextField) {
        text = Formatter.decimal.string(for: amount)
    }
}
```

---

```
extension NumberFormatter {
    convenience init(numberStyle: Style) {
        self.init()
        self.numberStyle = numberStyle
    }
}
struct Formatter {
    static let decimal = NumberFormatter(numberStyle: .decimal)
}
extension UITextField {
    var string: String { return text ?? "" }
}

extension String {
    private static var digitsPattern = UnicodeScalar("0")..."9"
    var digits: String {
        return unicodeScalars.filter { String.digitsPattern ~= $0 }.string
    }
}

extension Sequence where Iterator.Element == UnicodeScalar {
    var string: String { return String(String.UnicodeScalarView(self)) }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I prefer a `UITextFieldDelegate` solution, because editingChanged event will only trigger after the textfield's text already changed. Which means user can see the delay

Comment: @JayVDiyk there is no delay. The field it is connected to editing changed UIControlEvent. Have you tried the sample project?

Comment: Thank you, it works. I have to wait 22 hours for the bounty

Comment: @JayVDiyk why did you gave the bounty to the other answer?

Comment: Oh shoot @LeoDabus i did not take a look carefully when I gave the bounty. Sorry about that

Comment: @JayVDiyk kkkkk no problem.

Comment: This works great for none decimal. for decimal it does not work: eg. 1,000.90

Comment: @EKChhuon for me it works for both. Note that the number of fractional decimal digits depends on the locale you set if fixed or the device’s locale if using current locale

Answer (score 2):

> Simple thing i came up with fully tested on Swift 2.0

you can use the any of the textField delegate see which one suites you

```
         let price = Int(textField.text!)

        let _curFormatter : NSNumberFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()

        _curFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.CurrencyStyle

        _curFormatter.currencyCode = "INR"

        _curFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 0

        let total = _curFormatter.stringFromNumber(price!)

        textField.text = total
```

[image: OUTPUT]