# Why Is UITextField.text An Optional?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

It starts out as an empty string instead of nil. Even when it is explicitly set to nil it remains an empty string. I don't get it. Perhaps to make it easy to clear by assigning nil? Writing code with it is clunky.

```
var textField = UITextField()
print(textField.text) // prints "Optional("")"
textField.text = nil
print(textField.text) // prints "Optional("")"
```

Comment: Related (duplicate?): [Why was UITextField's text property changed to an optional in Swift 2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32621022/why-was-uitextfields-text-property-changed-to-an-optional-in-swift-2)

Comment: @MartinR Not a duplicate, I think. The question here is _why_ `text` is an Optional, since it is never `nil`. The question _there_ is how to _treat_ `text` given that it _is_ an Optional.

Comment: @matt: At least closely related. The title there says "*Why ...*"

Comment: @MartinR But none of the answers answer that. They are only about _how_ (to cope). Sulthan's is the first attempt at an answer to this question that I've ever seen.

Comment: @matt: Agreed..

Comment: To me, this question is about a design decision made by Apple, which is off topic for Stack Overflow as a primarily opinion-based question (only the Apple engineers who wrote the code can answer).

Comment: @JAL I think it's worse than that; I think it's fair to call it a bug, and I've added an answer saying so.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

This is a historical thing. `UITextField` does not make any difference between an empty string and a `nil` string. In Objective-C there was no need to make a difference between them because you can call methods on `nil` in Objective-C.

Also, there was no way in Objective-C to prevent users from assigning `nil` to a property.
The resulting contract is that `text` can be optional. In Objective-C that makes no difference.

In Swift there is not much we can do because `UITextField.text` contract would have to change, possibly breaking lots of already written code. Note that even if `nil` is never returned from the method, you can still assign `nil` to reset the value.

You can find hundreds of similar situations in the old APIs.

Comment: So, does that mean that I can always force unwrap it?

Comment: @Verticon No, you can always use `?? ""`.

Comment: Are you sure? Check out my edited question: even after assigning nil it still returns .some("")

Comment: Actually you can create an extension to UITextField and add a string property to `return text ?? ""` http://stackoverflow.com/a/35692194/2303865

Comment: @Verticon I don't think you understand my explanation. I am explaining why `text` is an optional. I haven't said you don't have to handle the optional.

Comment: @Sulthan Thank you for your answer and it makes sense. I was just pointing out that it seems to never be nil and that therefore I could always force unwrap it. Perhaps I should treat this as undocumented behavior upon which I should not rely?

Comment: In the current UIKit implementation, `text` will never be nil. However, it's not documented as such, so it's safer to assume it could be nil.

Comment: I'm not sure this really answers the question. I _can't_ "find hundreds of similar situations." The whole idea of hand-tweaking the APIs was to remove unnecessary Optionals. Hundreds of values can _theoretically_ be `nil` but in fact never will be, and in Swift they are therefore _not_ Optionals. _This_ value can never be `nil`; even if Objective-C code sets it to `nil`, it doesn't become `nil`. And making it nonOptional in Swift wouldn't "break" anything whatever. So it makes no sense that it's an Optional in Swift. I think the right answer is that it's a bug.

Comment: @matt There is valid objective-c and even Swift code calling `field.text = nil`. Making `text` non optional would make all that code invalid. Therefore making the property non-optional is not that easy.

Comment: The Swift code calling `field.text = nil` would simply have to be replaced by `field.text = ""`. No worse than the kind of breakage we've been through dozens of times during the Swift version-update process. And the Objective-C code could just go on working.

Answer (score 34):

I feel strongly enough about this that I'm repeating my comment on Sulthan's answer as an alternative answer.

I'm not sure Sulthan's answer really answers the question.

I *can't* "find hundreds of similar situations." That's because they are no longer there. They were there in Swift 1, but that was a long time ago. Since then, the APIs have been hand-tweaked to eliminate them. This one wasn't eliminated.

The whole idea of hand-tweaking the APIs was to remove unnecessary Optionals. Hundreds of values can *theoretically* be `nil` but in fact never will be, and in Swift they are therefore *not* Optionals. *This* value can never be `nil`; even if Objective-C code sets it to `nil`, it doesn't become `nil`. And making it nonOptional in Swift wouldn't "break" anything whatsoever. So it makes no sense that it's an Optional in Swift.

I think the right answer, therefore, is that it's a bug. During IUO removal in the course of hand-tweaking the APIs in the run-up to Swift 2.0, the label and text field `text` properties should have been characterized as a nonOptional String, but they weren't.

Comment: I like it. Hopefully the Swift team is paying attention.

Comment: So do you see any harm in force unwrapping it all the time?

Comment: @toddg I always do force unwrap it, and that's never done _me_ any harm.

Comment: I've filed a bug radar #46580238 https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=6175370021699584 It would be nice to get this fixed, as it doesn't make sense.