# Trying to avoid finding nil unwrapping optional values

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to do some math with user input numbers I get from UITextFields. The problem, there could be nothing in the TextField, in that case the value should be set to zero. I tried the guard statement but it seems I use it the wrong way:

```
    guard let number = numberTextField.text else{ let number = 0}
```

What is wrong with this code? What should I change?

Comment: If there is nothing in the Textfield you wont get nil. numberTextField.text will be empty string ""

Comment: @RajeshkumarR I'm looking at the documentation, and `UITextField`'s `text` property is optional. I don't know *why* it's optional, but it's in the docs...

Comment: @CharlesSrstka Yes. UITextField's text property is optional. But you'll never get nil even if you assign nil to the text property. So no need to use if let or guard for unwrapping the text.

Comment: @RajeshkumarR Intuitively, it does seem that the property should never contain `nil`. However, presumably the development team found some edge case where it can return `nil`, or else they wouldn't have marked it as optional. In any case, it's easy enough to provide a default value using the `??` operator.

Comment: @CharlesSrstka Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42861357/7250862)

Comment: @RajeshkumarR It's still optional, though, and the compiler still won't let you use it without unwrapping it. Even the answer you linked to recommends using `??` to unwrap.

Comment: @CharlesSrstka Yes. I agree. But `let number = Int(numberTextField.text!) ?? 0` is enough I guess. Why we need to use `flapMap`?

Comment: @RajeshkumarR The force-unwrap operator is very ugly when there's a simple alternative. Plus, the author of the answer you linked to doesn't seem to be an Apple employee, and I'm a bit hesitant to accept that something will *never* happen from someone who doesn't have access to the source code (plus, making it nil just for setting makes no sense. Even if the Objective-C property can be set to `nil` when `@""` would be perfectly fine, it doesn't mean the Swift version needs to do that). Just unwrap, it's easy. If you don't like `flatMap`, you can just `Int(numberField.text ?? "") ?? 0`.

Answer (score 4):

The `guard` statement cannot be used, because it requires you to exit from the function if the condition is `false`. Instead, you should use the `??` operator:

```
let number = numberTextField.text.flatMap { Int($0) } ?? 0
```

Why `flatMap`? Because we need to convert the `String` to an `Int` (or a `Double`, if this may contain a floating-point value) in order for it to be the same type as the `0`. `flatMap` on an optional returns the value inside the closure if `text` is not `nil`, but returns `nil` if it is. In either case you'll end up with an optional `Int`, which is then made non-optional by supplying the default value of `0` via the `??` operator.

Comment: FYI - `guard` requires you to exit the block the guard is in. Of course if the guard is at the top of the function, it means you must exit the function. But not all guards are at the top of a function.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use a default value instead of a guard to get the behavior you desire.

```
let number = Double(numberTextField.text) ?? 0
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this got down voted. Seems like its the correct solution. Operator ?? is the same as saying "numberTextField.text != nil ? numberTextField.text! : 0"

Comment: I'm not sure either.

Comment: The problem with this is that the types don't match. What type is `number` after this code executes? Is it a number or a string?

Answer (score -1):

Nothing means empty string rather than nil
"guard let" is used to check nil value

Let try the method below

```
if numberTextField.text.isEmpty {
   let number = 0
}
```