# Swift "expected expression in list of expressions" and unwrapped?

Tags: ios, swift

I am suppose to combine a defined variable and text from a text field.

This is what is giving me the problem.

```
var urlAddOn = mobileMakersLink + urlAddOnTextField.text
```

It is saying that it

> Expected expression in list of expressions" and "Value of optional
>   type 'String?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?

Here is the entire function.

```
@IBAction func stretchThree(_ sender: UIButton)
{
    urlAddOnTextField.resignFirstResponder()

    var mobileMakersLink :String = String(http://mobilemakersedu.org/)
    var urlAddOn = mobileMakersLink + urlAddOnTextField.text

    let myUrl = NSURL(string: urlAddOn)
    let svc = SFSafariViewController(URL: myUrl!)
    svc.delegate = self
    self.presentViewController(svc, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Comment: [Swift Optionals](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional) explained by Apple. Please read it.

Answer (score 0):

Just change `urlAddOnTextField.text` to `urlAddOnTextField.text!`.

If curious, check this link [Why Is UITextField.text An Optional?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42861115/why-is-uitextfield-text-an-optional)

Comment: @Moritz There is now way in Swift to have nil in UiTexfield text

Comment: @Moritz Even if you assign nil to text property, there is now way you would receive nil upon call. You better check, before you say.

Comment: @Moritz I've added an explanation link.