# What is best practice, to enclose the value of a UITextField in a Computed property or in a Closure

Tags: swift, closures, computed-properties

If you have a `UITextField` and you know you will constantly reference its value and you will use the value as a `Double` which of the following two samples make more sense? Or better yet, does any of the two make sense? Is this a good practice to follow?

#### Computed Property

```
var fieldValue:Double {
    get{
        return Double(someField.text! ?? "0") as! Double
    }   
}
```

#### Store Property as Closure

```
var fieldValue:Double = {
    return Double(someField.text! ?? "0") as! Double
}()
```

Comment: Why are you force casting a `Double` into a `Double`? Also, why are you providing a default value to a force unwrapped value (which isn't an optional anymore)?

Comment: Just to clarify, is this how you would get the value as a `Double`?  `var fieldValue: Double { Double(someField.text!) ?? 0 }`  As suggested by Mojtaba Hosseini.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second option is **NOT** going to update *constantly*. Since it's not stored **as a** closure! It stored **using a** closure *just once*.

So in this question, you have only the first option as a choice.

## Some helpful notes:

1. Force unwrapping and using nil coalescing operator at same time is nonesence:

```
Double(someField.text! ?? "0") // exclamation mark is nonesense here
```

2. In get-only computed properties, you can get rid of the `get` keyword:

```
var fieldValue: Double {
    return Double(someField.text ?? "0") as! Double
}
```

3. You don't need to forcecast a `Double` to `Double`:

```
var fieldValue: Double {
    return Double(someField.text ?? "0")!
}
```

4. Since Swift 5.1, you don't need `return` keyword for single line expressions:

```
var fieldValue: Double { Double(someField.text ?? "0")! }
```

5. Seems like you need a `0` as a default value if initializer failed to initialize a `Double` from the text, right?! So replace the force unwrap with a default value as well:

```
var fieldValue: Double { Double(someField.text ?? "0") ?? 0 }
```

6. As @Dávid Pásztor mentioned and [referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42861115/why-is-uitextfield-text-an-optional), It is safe to force unwrap `UITextField().text`, so someField.text ?? "0" is just as useless as someField.text! ?? "0", since UITextField.text is guaranteed to be non-nil, it is only Optional due to Obj-C legacy support. So it could if you are not referencing an `Obj-C`, you can use it like:

```
var fieldValue: Double { Double(someField.text!) ?? 0 }
```

## Other options:

You can use `valueChanged` event of the `textField` to get notified and react in a function if you want:

```
// Somewhere soon like `viewDidLoad`
    someField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(someFieldChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
    }
    
    @objc private func someFieldChanged(_ sender: UITextField) {
        let fieldValue = Double(sender.text ?? "0") ?? 0
        ,,,
    }
```

Also you can use delegate methods for this. It's up to you.

Comment: It is safe to force unwrap `UITextField.text`, so `someField.text ?? "0"` is just as useless as `someField.text! ?? "0"`, since `UITextField.text` is guaranteed to be non-nil, it is only Optional due to Obj-C legacy support. Have a look at [Why is UITextField.text Optional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42861115/why-is-uitextfield-text-an-optional)

Comment: @ Mojtaba Hosseini - Thanks a lot for the good suggestions! I guess you meant `exclamation point` not question mark.

Comment: @DávidPásztor yes it's useless in pure Swift code but makes sense sometimes. Thanks for mentioning that. I added that to my answer respecting your name.