# How to return in a function if a variable is nil?

Tags: swift, error-handling

I am setting a variable to the `doubleValue` of a `UITextField` with the following,

```
let enteredTargetDays : Double = numberFormatter.number(from: textField2.text!)?.doubleValue ?? 0.00
```

This ensures that even if the `textField2.text` is `nil` and a `doubleValue` cannot be extrapolated, `0.00` will return. But what if I don't want a default value, and just want the function to return if the `textField2.text` is nil?

Is the only way to do this to first check `textField2.text` for `nil` before setting the variable, or is there is a quicker, one-liner, Swifty way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not wanting to use a default value and just wanting the function to return is exactly what `guard` statements are for:

```
func yourFunction() {
    guard let enteredTargetDays = numberFormatter.number(from: textField2.text ?? "")?.doubleValue else {
        return
    }

    // do something with `enteredTargetDays` here
}
```

Comment: Just a follow up question: it would make sense to also use textField2.text! instead of providing a default value for that if I wanted to strictly based off what was present, and that would be acceptable?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not quite sure I understand your follow-up question.

Comment: So, in your answer, you have textField2.text ?? "", but I could use textField2.text! instead and if textField2.text was nil the guard would still catch it and return?

Comment: Oh, sure you could use `textField2.text!` since the `text` property of `UITextField` is [pretty much guaranteed to never be nil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42861115/why-is-uitextfield-text-an-optional). I just personally hate using the force-unwrap operator in all cases so I opted to use the nil-coalescing operator (aka `??`) there instead. And yes even if the textfield's text was empty/nil, the guard will still catch this because the `numberFormatter` will return nil from the call to `number(from:)` (because you can't really make a number from an empty string).

Comment: Ah, that makes sense! Thank you for explaining that. I actually quickly realized this because when I started using guard, I had to check for an empty string instead of nil. Makes sense.