# Although the email & password fields are empty, I'm moving to the next screen

Tags: swift, firebase, uistoryboardsegue

I'm not sure why, but the segue is triggered even when the email & password field are empty.
How can it possibly be?

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class RegisterViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var errorLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var emailTextfield: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var passwordTextfield: UITextField!



@IBAction func registerPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    
    if let email = emailTextfield.text, let password = passwordTextfield.text {
        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { authResult, error in
            if let e = error {
                self.errorLabel.text = e.localizedDescription
            } else {
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "RegisterToChat", sender: self)
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! You should [edit] your question to include all relevant code as text using proper code formatting.

Answer (score 1):

The `text` property of `UITextField`s is not `nil` when the text field is empty. You need to check the `isEmpty` property of `textField.text` to check for that.

```
if let email = emailTextField.text, let password = passwordTextField.text, !email.isEmpty, !password.isEmpty { ...
```

Actually, `UITextField.text` can never be `nil`. The property is only `Optional` due to it being a legacy, Objective-C class. For more information on this, check [Why is UITextField.text an Optional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42861115/why-is-uitextfield-text-an-optional).