# How to check multiple textfields are nil or not and enable button accordingly in swift

Tags: swift, uibutton, uitextfield

I need to enable **nextBtn** when all textfields has some text only

tried below code: but with this code when i tap on first textfield then my `nextBtn` becomes enabled why? how to make `nextBtn` enable after filling the all textfields only. please guide me

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    nextBtn.isEnabled = false
    nextBtn.alpha = 0.5
}

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    
    if fullNameTextField.text == nil{
        nextBtn.alpha = 0.5
        nextBtn.isEnabled = false
    }
    else if dateOfBirthTextField.text == nil{
        nextBtn.alpha = 0.5
        nextBtn.isEnabled = false
    }
    else if schoolNameTextField.text == nil{
        nextBtn.alpha = 0.5
        nextBtn.isEnabled = false
    }
    else if schoolLocationTextField.text == nil{
        nextBtn.alpha = 0.5
        nextBtn.isEnabled = false
    }
    else if gradeClassTextField.text == nil{
        nextBtn.alpha = 0.5
        nextBtn.isEnabled = false
    }
    else{
        nextBtn.alpha = 1
        nextBtn.isEnabled = true
    }
}
```

**edit**: i have tried like this. now after taping on second textfield then `nextBtn` becomes enable why? please guide me

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

    if fullNameTextField.text == "", dateOfBirthTextField.text == "", schoolNameTextField.text == "", gradeClassTextField.text == ""{
        nextBtn.alpha = 0.5
        nextBtn.isEnabled = false
    }
    else{
        nextBtn.alpha = 1
        nextBtn.isEnabled = true
    }
}
```

Comment: For "has some text" the test for equality with nil will not work. A text field's text can be empty without being nil. For example `""` is an empty string but it is not nil.

Comment: @matt, I am so confused, if i check `fullNameTextField.text == ""` like this in same above structure then if i fill all textfields then also `nextBtn ` not changed

Comment: @matt, could you guide me to achieve to enable `nextBtn ` when all textfields are filled only

Comment: That's what I'm doing. You have to check two things, nil and empty. And you have to check for all of the text fields, not for each of them individually. And didBeginEditing is the wrong place to check.

Comment: `if fullNameTextField.text == "",` should be  `if fullNameTextField.text == "" || `   as `,` acts like `&&` and in your case if any not if all

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42861115/why-is-uitextfield-text-an-optional

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do it by doing it like this

```
let fields = [fullNameTextField, dateOfBirthTextField, schoolNameTextField, schoolLocationTextField, gradeClassTextField]
let isVaildFields = fields.allSatisfy { field in
            !field.text.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines).isEmpty
         } 
if isVaildFields {
    nextBtn.alpha = 1
    nextBtn.isEnabled = true
} else {
    nextBtn.alpha = 0.5
    nextBtn.isEnabled = false
}
```

Comment: error: Cannot use instance member 'dateOfBirthTextField' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available for this line 'let fields = [fullNameTextField, dateOfBirthTextField, schoolNameTextField, schoolLocationTextField, gradeClassTextField]'

Comment: can u write code for individual textfields bcz at this point i cant create array of textfields

Comment: Yeah, sure i'll do it.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it is like

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var fullNameTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var dateOfBirthTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var schoolNameTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var schoolLocationTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var gradeClassTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var nextBtn: UIButton!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        nextBtn.isEnabled = false
        nextBtn.alpha = 0.5
    }

    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        let fields = [fullNameTextField, dateOfBirthTextField, schoolNameTextField,
                      schoolLocationTextField, gradeClassTextField]
        let isValidFields = fields.allSatisfy {
            !($0?.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines).isEmpty ?? true)
        }
        
        if isValidFields {
            nextBtn.alpha = 1
            nextBtn.isEnabled = true
        } else {
            nextBtn.alpha = 0.5
            nextBtn.isEnabled = false
        }
    }
}
```

You can also do it by creating list of text field `@IBOutlet`, Like following:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet var textFields: [UITextField]!
    @IBOutlet weak var nextBtn: UIButton!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        nextBtn.isEnabled = false
        nextBtn.alpha = 0.5
    }

    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        let isValidFields = textFields.allSatisfy {
            !($0.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines).isEmpty ?? true)
        }
        
        if isValidFields {
            nextBtn.alpha = 1
            nextBtn.isEnabled = true
        } else {
            nextBtn.alpha = 0.5
            nextBtn.isEnabled = false
        }
    }
}
```

And if you only want to do it for individual textfields, you can simply do like this.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var fullNameTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var dateOfBirthTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var schoolNameTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var schoolLocationTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var gradeClassTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var nextBtn: UIButton!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        nextBtn.isEnabled = false
        nextBtn.alpha = 0.5
    }
    
    func isValid(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        return !(textField.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines).isEmpty ?? true)
    }

    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        if isValid(fullNameTextField), isValid(dateOfBirthTextField),
           isValid(schoolNameTextField), isValid(schoolLocationTextField),
           isValid(gradeClassTextField) {
            nextBtn.alpha = 1
            nextBtn.isEnabled = true
        } else {
            nextBtn.alpha = 0.5
            nextBtn.isEnabled = false
        }
    }
}
```